# Ошибки выполняя git pull

Tags: git, git-pull

вСЕМ привет!
Получил от другого разработчика проект  в виде .zip-файла и внеся изменения перевел его на наш bitbucket и 
загружаю его на хостинг (поменяв origin)
И выполнив

```
# git pull origin master

# git stash
```

Получаю список в несколько десятков ошибок вида:

```
uto-merging app/Http/Controllers/Admin/DepartmentController.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in app/Http/Controllers/Admin/DepartmentController.php
Auto-merging app/Http/Controllers/Admin/ClientController.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in app/Http/Controllers/Admin/ClientController.php
Auto-merging app/Http/Controllers/Admin/BookingController.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in app/Http/Controllers/Admin/BookingController.php
Auto-merging .DS_Store
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .DS_Store
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
root@Box-Booking-Server:/var/www/html/boxbooking# git config --local core.autocrlf false
root@Box-Booking-Server:/var/www/html/boxbooking# git pull origin master
error: Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

Попытался выполнить:

```
git config --local core.autocrlf false

# git config -l
user.email=user@mail.com
user.name=user
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.autocrlf=false
remote.origin.url=https://user@bitbucket.org/client/project.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
root@Box-Booking-Server:/var/www/html/boxbooking# git log
commit 7f8d408cd1616eb7cd8aeebd6817ddab9c588dea
Merge: e23e68a 34b2bce
```

В списке лога выводит длинный список комитов и первый(последний по времени)

```
# git log
commit 7f8d408cd1616eb7cd8aeebd6817ddab9c588dea
Merge: e23e68a 34b2bce
Author: developer <developer@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jun 29 15:18:16 2018 +0000

    Task ...

commit 34b2bceed4aa702e50cba2ac431428d1dcaddbef
Author: developer <developer@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jun 29 17:51:08 2018 +0300

    fix migration

commit 8d769c6574a15095fa4818396017f9736ba84554
Author: developer <developer@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jun 29 17:46:00 2018 +0300

    migration changed
```

1) я так понимаю мне нужно выполнить

```
git rebase -i 7f8d408cd1616eb7cd8aeebd6817ddab9c588dea^
```

чтобы откатить последним изменениям(до того как я пытался выполнить git pull origin master )
и вернуть сайт на пред состояние?

2) Не совсем понятна ошибка - это связано с различными настройками core.autocrlf илт что-то иное и как ее лечить ?

Спасибо !

Comment: Непонятно ни в какой форме содержимое архива, ни что вы делали с ним, ни против чего вы запускаете приведенные команды.

Comment: Не выглядит так что проблема в core.autocrlf. Если исходить из текста ошибки, вы делаете pull, но у вас произошли конфликты, которые нужно разрешить.